# Is it possible to tell the Flash Player to use AVM1 instead of AVM2?

Tags: adobe, flash, flashvars

It's my understanding that the Adobe Flash Player has two ActionScript Virtual machines.  AVM1 and AVM2.  It is supposed to detect whether a swf contains ActionScript 1/2 or ActionScript 3 and automatically select the proper virtual machine.  The latest releases of the Flash Player 10.0.40+.x are breaking our oldest content.  We speculate that it is not detecting the version properly because flashlog.txt reveals lots warnings about "undeclared" variables.  Our oldest code uses ActionScript 1 and 2 and thus all variables are of course undeclared by AVM2 standards.  So, we're wondering if we can do something, short of recompiling 10 years worth of products to make the latest Flash Player run our products.  One idea is to pass in a version number through FlashVars, and I'm hoping someone out there might know for sure if this is worth persuing.

Comment: Separately, do you know how to determine if swf contains AVM1 or AVM2?

Comment: The swf itself does not contain the (A)ctionscript (V)irtual (M)achine; however, you can identify the target version by loading the swf as bytes and parsing out the 4th byte to get the version number.  I do this when loading old swfs that were structured to begin playing immediately, but I no longer want to play immediately in our new framework.  This person's site demonstrates manipulating the file version. http://code.google.com/p/as3-classes/source/browse/trunk/org/lzyy/util/ForcibleLoader.as

Comment: Getting the version number of the targeted player isn't going to tell you weather or not the content is AVM1 or AVM2 content. Weather the bytecode is actionscript 2 or actionscript 3 is going to determine that. Also, even if the content was actionscript 3 and the main instance was an AVM2 instance, that swf could load in AS1/2 (avm1) bytecode and thus the AVM1 would be called to process that bytecode. So unfortunately, version numbers are not going to help you determine weather the bytecode is AVM1 or AVM2.

Comment: Also I'm not sure that the issue is what you're thinking it is. The flashlog is going to show those kinds of warning regardless because of how loose actionscript 1 and 2 are regarding dynamic typing. AS1 and 2 in nature are like the polar opposite of AS3. AS3 being a strict-typed language and AS1/2 being dynamic and just plain not really caring about types at all, everything is just an object. So these warnings have nothing to do with avm1/2 but rather they're just warnings about your coding practices that you won't ever see unless you are using a debugger player.